# Does rollup have a plugin that compile static import into dynamic import?

Tags: reactjs, rollup

I have same code like this

```
// index.tsx
export { modal } from './modal'
export { alert } from './alert'
```

I want to implement code split for **modal** and **alert** in rollup.

Then, i thought of compile static import into dynamic import, but not find related plugin.

Is there a related plugin or good solution? thanks a million!